# Class A's definition requires class B's definition, how do I expose A's public functions without exposing B's definition?

Tags: c++, oop, templates

Let's say I have the following library design: We are exposing class `A` for the library users, but not class `B`. However, class `A` generates instances of class `B` for internal consumption. There are implementation requirements that `A` must generate instances of `B` using a private function (i.e., `A::getOneB()`). Also, the generated instance must be wrapped in a smart pointer for safe memory management.

So the question is: **A.hpp** must include **B.hpp** so the return type of `A::getOneB` can be instantiated, but that would leak out `B`'s definition to the clients who are including **A.hpp**. How do we prevent that?

**A.hpp** // we are exporting this for client code to use A::foo().

```
#include "B.hpp"
class A {
public:
    void foo(); // the public API
private:
    std::unique_ptr<B> getOneB(); // the internal API that returns a fresh B to consume. We need smart pointer for auto memory management.
};
```

**B.hpp** // we are not exporting this, we don't want client code to know about B.

```
class B {
};
```

Comment: @ChrisMM `unique_ptr` requires a complete type.

Comment: did you consider PIMPL paradigm https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl, https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/01/pimpl.html, etc Google...

Comment: @NathanOliver, my bad. Was thinking of `shared_ptr`

Comment: Have you learned about *forward declarations*?

Comment: @JesperJuhl, like @ NathanOliver said, forward declarations would not help because the class definition of B is required.

Answer (score 2):

> Class A's definition requires class B's definition, how do I expose A's public functions without exposing B's definition?

If B's definition is needed, then you cannot avoid the exposure of B's definition. So, the solution is to change the premise: Change A so that its definition no longer depends on definition of B.

In this case, simply replace the member function with free function, which doesn't need to be declared in the header that defines A.

Another approach is to introduce an opaque wrapper class:

```
struct BWrapper;
class A {
    BWrapper getOneB();
};

// outside the header;
#include "B.hpp"
struct BWrapper {
    std::unique_ptr<B> b_ptr;
};
BWrapper A::getOneB() {
   ...
```

Comment: Are you suggesting designating getOneB() out to another class and letting A hold an instance of that class?

Comment: @DXZ I thought that `B` was a member of the class when I wrote the answer. Now that I see it is a function, it is unclear why it is a member function. Perhaps simplest solution is to simply to replace it with a free function that doesn't need to be declared within the class.

Comment: That's surely one way out.